# Different locale in PHP-FPM vs PHP

Tags: php, apache2, locale, setlocale

I'm struggling with an encoding problem switching from regular PHP to PHP-FPM. The php.ini's are the same. It seems as if php-fpm is picking up the locale settings from the user that the service is running.

**PHP:**

Code: `$currentLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); echo $currentLocale;`

Output: `C`

**PHP-FPM:**

Code: `$currentLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0); echo $currentLocale;`

Output: `LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C`

The goal is to get "C" in PHP-FPM, the same as in PHP (old application using utf8-encode). Ubuntu server with Apache2